# Can we create a fully end to end web application by using Vaadin only

Tags: java, spring-mvc, vaadin

I just started learning Vaadin.It has integration support with hibernate, very flexible and attractive UI interface and has CDI support same as Spring.So, my question is just like Spring can we create a web application only using Vaadin without using any other framework.Or vaadin is only for UI stuffs and it only maps the UI calls to our service class written in plain java using VaadinServlet?Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: Vaadin does the UI and the server part of your web application. It then depends on your requirements/environment if you use spring/jpa or other technologies on the server side to implement your business logic and persistence layer. Vaadin has support for many of them

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin is pratically a 360° framework to develop web application in Java.
His client-side is based on GWT (Google Web Toolkit) which magic is to convert the Java you write in plain HTML/CSS/Javascript (Vaadin ltd is also one of the steering committee of the GWT consortium).
Develop in GWT was quite a breath of fresh air in those years but Vaadin took it to the next level: you actually don't have to mess with the client side (unless you need some very specific customization) but the whole code is server based, and "presentation" classes like "Component" & co will be automatically rendered client side, the connection between automatically handled through the Vaadin engine.
This allow you faster then ever application development where you only have to take care of how you present your data and your business logic.
Said that, Vaadin is a base, you can do everything with it. If you need something specific you can take a look at the add-on the very active community does or integrate basically everything you might need over it since it acts like every Java EE web application

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin is more than GWT ( UIs ) , Valo theme or ( just front-end tier ). with Vaadin Simply you can build your Full ( SPA -> Single Page Application ). very modern UIs + powerfull add-ons + MVP ( Model-View-Presenter )+Testing tools + Window Builder ( UI Designer ) - cross browsers issue .very good docs ( [the book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/documentation)  ) your responsive designe . and more something like . JPAContainer & CDI add-on . you can find more and more just start believe in VAADIN  and  [Thinging Of U and I }>](http://vaadin.com)